# MinGW-w64 detect revision/patch number at compile time

Tags: mingw-w64

Recent MinGW version ([v5.0.2](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/35754067/)) introduced some DirectX updates which declare some XInput structs that are already defined in SDL(2.0.4). Preventing it from compiling. I would like to add some macros around SDL's `XINPUT_GAMEPAD_EX` and `XINPUT_STATE_EX` structs to prevent them from being declared on that particular MinGW-w64 version.

I can't test for GCC 6.3.0 because it worked on the previous revision. Just this last one that causes the issue.

And I just can't find any information related to detecting the patch/revision number. Some compile time macro or something. There's only information on finding the the major/minor version numbers. I need to detect that `.2`.

Comment: There are tons of Q/A here explaining how to compile an empty file with gcc -E -dM empty.c with the old version, with the new version, and then running diff on those outputs to see what might let you distinguish them.

Comment: I'm not interested in finding the GCC version. I'm interested in finding the patch/revision number of MinGW-w64. For which I can't seem to find any information. I've already tried what you mentioned.

Comment: You should have said that you had already tried it. If there is no difference in preprocessor output, unless you can find a file on which to test __has_include, this means you have to perform a test in some early configuration step (configure/cmake/...), in which case you might as well test the behavior you want to change, i.e. try compiling a file that includes directX and defines the problematic XInput structs.